# adding metric in cloudwatch log

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Elastic Beanstalk generated logs in five file by default. When cloudwatch streaming log is enabled it shows error.log access.log, eb.log. But i want catilina.out log or tomcat log also in cloudwatch log. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own logs to Cloudwatch using an additional configuration file:

```
/etc/awslogs/config/awslogs.conf
```

As an example I use the following file to steam all the laravel logs for an application to cloudwatch:

```
[laravel.log]
file = /var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel*
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = {instance_id}
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = prod-laravel
multi_line_start_pattern = {datetime_format}
```

When adding or updated the file be sure to restart the awslogs daemon too.

More information can be found at  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html.

Comment: will it transfer the logs of catalina.out into cloudwatch?
in file parameter what to give

Comment: the **file** attribute in my example is the name of the file it will stream. So you just need to make sure that is the path to your catalina.out file.  The **log_group_name** is the name it will appear as in cloudwatch.

Comment: And can we change the name of log group in elastic beanstalk. Because when we enable log stream it by default sets the log group name for 5 files/stream

Comment: Yes, using **log_group_name**

Comment: are their any java api for setting this configurations? like for
file = /var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel*
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = {instance_id}
and all those

Comment: I can't say. I use .ebextensions as part of my project to deploy and manage this configuration.

Comment: any alternate way to do this? What if i say i don't want to login into my linux instance all the time

Comment: for editing /etc/awslogs/config/awslogs.conf i will have to login into linux instance. Right? I don't want to login into that. When i will deploy my war file from that it should config cloudwatch logs.

Answer (score 0):

I've detailed in a new [Medium blog](https://codingrob.medium.com/how-to-setup-aws-elasticbeanstalk-to-stream-your-custom-application-logs-to-cloudwatch-d5c877eaa242) how this all works and an example .ebextensions file and where to put it.

In summary you'll need to setup a Policy, attach it to the Elastic Beanstalk EC2 role, add an .ebextensions file to your app and ensure that file references *exactly* the right path and filename that you want to stream.

Below is an excerpt that you might be able to use the article explains how to find and verify the right folder/file(s) to stream.

```
packages:
  yum:
    awslogs: []

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: StreamLogs
    value: true
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: DeleteOnTerminate
    value: false
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: RetentionInDays
    value: 90

files:
  "/etc/awslogs/awscli.conf" :
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [plugins]
      cwlogs = cwlogs
      [default]
      region = `{"Ref":"AWS::Region"}`

  "/etc/awslogs/config/logs.conf" :
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [/var/log/tomcat/localhost.log]
      log_group_name = `{"Fn::Join":["/", ["/aws/elasticbeanstalk", { "Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, "var/log/tomcat/localhost.log"]]}`
      log_stream_name = {instance_id}
      file = /var/log/tomcat/localhost.*

      [/var/log/tomcat/catalina.log]
      log_group_name = `{"Fn::Join":["/", ["/aws/elasticbeanstalk", { "Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, "var/log/tomcat/catalina.log"]]}`
      log_stream_name = {instance_id}
      file = /var/log/tomcat/catalina.*

      [/var/log/tomcat/localhost_access_log.txt]
      log_group_name = `{"Fn::Join":["/", ["/aws/elasticbeanstalk", { "Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, "var/log/tomcat/access_log"]]}`
      log_stream_name = {instance_id}
      file = /var/log/tomcat/access_log.*

commands:
  "01":
    command: systemctl enable awslogsd.service
  "02":
    command: systemctl restart awslogsd
```